# Spring MVC with React Bootstrap / Material UI?

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, spring-mvc, material-ui

Is it possible to use a Spring MVC application to serve **React Bootstrap** **or Material UI** webpages from the Spring application?

If it is possible, what areas do I need to research?

Answer (score 1):

Check server side rendering with Spring MVC and react.
Example: 
https://patrickgrimard.io/2016/11/24/server-side-rendering-with-spring-boot-and-react/

Once you have the react being served by the server, you can add React Bootstrap or Material UI to your client application.